# AWS Lambda - sync vs async

Tags: amazon-web-services, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I've been playing with Lambda recently and am working on creating an API using API Gateway and Lambda. I have a lambda function in place that returns a JSON and an API Gateway endpoint that invokes the function. Everything works well with this simple setup.

I tried loadtesting the API gateway endpoint with the loadtest npm module. While Lambda processes the concurrent requests (albeit with an increase in mean latency over the course of execution), when I send it 40 requests per second or so, it starts throwing errors, only partially completing the requests.

I read in the documentation that by default, Lambda invocation is of type RequestResponse (which is what the API does right now) which is synchronous in nature, and it looks like it is non-blocking. For asynchronous invocation, the invocation type is Event. But lambda discards the return type for async invocations and the API returns nothing.

Is there something I am missing either with the sync, async or concurrency definitions in regards to AWS? Is there a better way to approach this problem? Any insight is helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use Synchronous execution if you want to get a return response from API Gateway. It doesn't make sense to use Async execution in this scenario. I think what you are missing is that while each Lambda execution is blocking, single threaded, there will be multiple instances of your function running in multiple Lambda server environments.

The default number of concurrent Lambda executions is fairly low, for safety reasons. This is to prevent you from accidentally writing a run-away Lambda process that would cost lots of money while you are still learning about Lambda. You need to [request an increase](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html) in the Lambda concurrent execution limit on your account.

Comment: Excellent! That's what I'd gathered so far but the documentation seemed a little ambiguous. I did notice that with higher concurrency (I pushed it up to 40) the mean latency increased. Is that just because we're operating under the 100 concurrent threshold limit, like you mentioned? For a higher requested concurrency, the speed should get better?

(I had a similar experience with memory on a lambda function. 128megs didnt cut it - avg latency was about 6 seconds. Increasing the memory to 512 brought it down to 800ms.)

Comment: Yes, once you increase that limit you should be able to get higher concurrency without a latency increase. I'd love to hear if that works well for you after your limit has been increased.

Comment: You might also want to look into enabling caching in API Gateway for increased performance of repeated requests. And you will want to make sure your rate limit settings in API Gateway aren't restricting the concurrent requests below the level you wish to support.

Comment: @MarkB But what about a situation where lambda `awaits` ( not blocking as you've answered) and meanwhile another request is arriving, will _that ( the first lambda )_ instance will be re-used ? ( because basically `awaits` return the control back to aws)  or will now there will be 2 instances? I didn't find any documentation

Comment: @RoyiNamir are you talking specifically about a JavaScript NodeJS AWS Lambda function using `await` to wait for a `Promise` to resolve?

Comment: @MarkB await on promise in JS or await on c# method , it don't think it matters (IMHO). all i'm asking is whether we pay on awaiting lambda. ( asynchronously waiting). I've read that it doesn;t matter and that we pay on overall execution time , regardless waiting or not. from `A-->Z`. and that it doesn't matter if lambda wasn't doing anything between `C-->T`. still , the price will be determined by  `A-->Z`. right ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Those do not "return control to AWS", they just unblock the Lambda function's execution so it could be doing other asynchronous actions while waiting on the promise to return. A Lambda function instance awaiting a promise like that does not get reused for another request.

Comment: @MarkB Thanks Mark , but  do we get a cheaper aws by using async/await  in lambdas?

Comment: @RoyiNamir no, Amazon can't just destroy the Lambda instance and reuse the physical hardware underlying the instance while your function is awaiting, and then somehow reconstitute the instance with all its in-memory state once your `await` finishes. You are ultimately paying for the physical hardware that your Lambda function is making use of, which is reserved for that Lambda function instance for the life of the function invocation.